# how to add ng-tags kind of view in filter view ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-tags-input

[How to achieve this kind of filter view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WpNc.png)

I want to create this component we are creating with ng-tags or any other library to be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this *appears* to be a request for a tutorial, which is off topic here.

Comment: Please go through with the tutorials.

Comment: If don't know please stop answering.Don't write for the sake of reputation.You are also not perfect in everything MR FAKE CHAMP

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

http://plnkr.co/edit/uGoVIUiDmEvyPdMA2gfc?p=preview

JS:

```
module.directive('processPercent', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'processPercent.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.percents = [
        'ALL',
        '10%',
        '20%',
        '30%',
        '40%',
        '50%',
        '60%',
        '70%',
        '80%',
        '90%',
        '100%'
      ];

      $scope.select = function(percent) {
        $scope.percent = percent;
      }
    },
    scope: {
      percent: '='
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<h3>PROCESS %</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" style="margin-right: 2px" ng-class="percent == p ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default'" ng-repeat="p in percents" ng-click="select(p)">
  {{ p }}
</button>
```

Usage:

```
<process-percent percent="percent"></process-percent>
```